# Server: The operation was cancelled because of locking conflicts (Analysis Services)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have a report application that is connected to an Olap cube in Analysis Services and every time that the application query the cube while the cube is processing I'm getting these errors:

1-Server:The operation was cancelled because of locking conflicts.

2-'MSOLAP' failed with no error message available, result code: E_FAIL(0x80004005)

The cube is updating every 10 minutes through a SQL Agent job with SSIS package that contain Analysis Services Processing task and the application is querying the cube every 15 minutes.

I was wondering if there is any option that I can set in the SSIS package or in the Cube.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid this problem I suggest you process a copy of the cube on another instance or server and then synchronise the processed cube to the server queried by your application.

This will prevent future locking problems and be invisible to the end user.

Comment: Can you give me a link or an example of how can I do it?

Comment: You should be able to generate a new xmla script that utilizes a synchronise command.

Comment: @JCACERES Don't have a link handy, but search for blogs or posts on "SSAS high availability" or "SSAS cube swap" for several related ideas. You can also join us on dba.stackexchange.com for more SQL or SSAS-specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

ForceCommitTimeOut Property of SSAS Tabular model is similar to the property in the multi dimensional model. These proerties are in milliseconds, so you can reproduce this issue in a functional environment by bringing down the value to 100ms, which would mean 1 second. The solution to this problem is to increase the value in this property to 0, which would mean wait until a lock is released.
[ForceCommitTimeOut Property of SSAS Tabulare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDsaX.png)